Is 9mm plywood strong enough for this application?
Sorry if this is a basic question I'm an absolute beginner. I'm trying to make a board with shelves on it for my Christmas market display.
If I used a back panel of 9mm (3/8") thick plywood, do you think it would hold 3 heavy ash wood shelves on it, if I secured with brackets and screws? Or should I opt for a lighter wood for the shelving?
The screws for the shelves will only be screwed through the plywood back board.
Once I'm setting up at the chalet I plan to just put 4 screws into each corner of the unit to mount onto the doors, so the screws for the shelves won't be screwed into the doors, (not allowed apart from the corners).


Hi, welcome to StackExchange. There's no absolute answer here but there's at least a chance that the answer is yes, 9mm plywood could be sufficient. However there are a lot of unknowns here, possibly the main one being just how much weight those heavyish shelves are. The simplest salve to worries is simply to use thicker plywood, and 12 and 18mm ply is available everywhere. Also siting the mounting screws at the corners is a concern, I'll let whoever formally answers your Question tackle that specific.

Can you do a rough sketch of your proposal? My interpretation is that there’s no way it’ll work, but I’m also not convinced my interpretation is accurate.

@AloysiusDefenestrate, FWIW successful tool panels can be based on 6mm untempered hardboard, & hold bracketed shelves mounted with screws from the back (so they pinch the backer rather than rely on any hold the threads might have). The panels are also mounted on the wall just by hanging there from French cleats, so there no added stiffening from the fixings to what's behind. Based on this, with the additional dimensional support from four corner screws, my bet is this arrangement could hold a great deal more than one would first suppose...... but of course thicker plywood sure wouldn't hurt.

@graphus — interesting… I hadn’t thought of shelves with brackets that way. (Still not 100% convinced, but more optimistic.)

@AloysiusDefenestrate, mind-bender for you, I had the opportunity to measure the backing of those tool panels I referred to and rather shockingly it's actually 3mm O_o
